# Updating the like count in Firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function where I post an image, like, and comment in the react-native app but hosted in Firebase real-time database all these elements are within a single post, now I want to update the post when a user presses the like icon to reflect in the app and in firebase to have 1 or any number.

```
export const Likes = ({ postId, initialLikes, likes }) => {
  const { countingLikes, setCountingLikes } = usePostContext();
  const {user} = useAuthContext()
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = React.useState(false); // Manage likes for each post separately

  const theme = useThemeContext();

  const ChangeLikesColor = async () => {
    try {
      // Toggle isLiked state
      const newIsLiked = !isLiked;
      setIsLiked(newIsLiked);
  
      // Update local likes count
      setCountingLikes(newIsLiked ? countingLikes + 1 : countingLikes - 1);
  
      // Update likes in Firebase
      await updateLikesForPost(postId, newIsLiked);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating likes:', error);
      // Revert local state changes if update fails
    }
  }
  // // Function to update likes for a specific post in Firebase
  const updateLikesForPost = async (postId, isLiked) => {
    try {
      const postRef = database.ref(`Posts/${user.uid}`);
  
      // Fetch the current likes count from Firebase
      const snapshot = await postRef.once('value');
      const data = snapshot.val();
  
      //find and retrieve the post Id and likes count
      if (data) {
        const posts = Object.entries(data).map(([postId, item]) => ({
          postId,
          likes: item.likes ,
        }))
        console.log(posts)
        
      } else {
        console.error('Post data not found.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating likes:', error);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize the isLiked state based on the initialLikes prop
    setIsLiked(initialLikes > 0);
  }, [initialLikes]);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={[LikesStyle.likeOverAllContainer, { backgroundColor: theme.likes.likeOverAllContainerBackgroundColor }]}>
        <View activeOpacity={changeOpacity} style={[LikesStyle.likesContainer, {}]}>

          <Tch onPress={ChangeLikesColor}>
            {/* Change the heart icon color based on the isLiked state */}
            <MatIcon
              name={isLiked ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
              size={28}
              style={[
                LikesStyle.likesIcon,
                { color: isLiked ? theme.likes.likeIconColor : theme.likes.blankHeart },
              ]}
            />
          </Tch>

          <Text style={[LikesStyle.likes, { color: theme.likes.likeTextColor }]}>Likes</Text>
          {/* Display the likes count from the static data or show 0 if likes is undefined or null */}
          <Text style={[LikesStyle.likes, { color: theme.likes.likeCountColor }]}>
            {likes !== undefined && likes !== null ? likes : 0}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

and this is how I access it in other components

```
<Likes postId={post.postId || post.id} initialLikes={post.likes} likes={post.likes} />
```

Here's my structure in firebase
Posts/userId/postId then after that I have post elements like
[
caption,comments,image,likes,time
]

I tried various ways to implement this but failed.

```
const updateLikesForPost = async (postId, isLiked) => {
  try {
    const userRef = database.ref(`Posts/${user.uid}`);

    // Fetch the current post data from Firebase
    const snapshot = await userRef.once('value');
    const data = snapshot.val();

    console.log('Fetched data:', data);

    // Check if the post exists in the data
    if (data && data[postId]) {
      console.log('Post data found:', data[postId]);

      // Update the likes count for the specific post
      const updatedLikes = isLiked ? data[postId].likes + 1 : data[postId].likes - 1;

      // Update likes for the specific post in the local state
      setPostUrls(prevUrls => {
        const updatedPosts = prevUrls.map(post => {
          if (post.postId === postId) {
            return {
              ...post,
              likes: updatedLikes
            };
          }
          return post;
        });
        return updatedPosts;
      });

      // Update likes count in Firebase
      const postRef = userRef.child(postId);
      await postRef.update({ likes: updatedLikes });

      console.log('Likes updated successfully.');
    } else {
      console.error('Post data not found.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating likes:', error);
  }
};
```

What I want to achieve is to have a successful update on the like component both reflected in firebase and in the app.

Comment: Please don't YELL AT US.

Comment: The use-case seems pretty clear. What isn't working about the code you shared? Any error message?

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen, I am getting the error that Post data not found, even tough the post is present, and the path is correct in Firebase for example if I try to retrieve it like the following code I get the post id and the current number of likes. look for second comment

Comment: const updateLikesForPost = async (postId, isLiked) => {
    try {
      const postRef = database.ref(`Posts/${user.uid}`);
      const snapshot = await postRef.once('value');
      const data = snapshot.val();
  
      //find and retrieve the post Id and likes count
      if (data) {
        const posts = Object.entries(data).map(([postId, item]) => ({
          postId,
          likes: item.likes ,
        }))
        console.log(posts)
  }

Comment: Don't post even more code in the comments please. There's already more code in your question than any of us is quickly going to digest. Instead of posting more info in the comments, **edit** your question (there's a small link under it) to include the exact error message you get and the complete stack trace for that. --- This would also be a good moment to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following that guidance increases the chances someone can help.